# Show Magento extension (static block) between toolbar and product list with if statement

Tags: xml, magento, php

I want to show the extension which I have installed, between the product list toolbar and products, that's done with

```
< reference name="product_list" >...
```

But I want to show the extension also, if there are no products, so a category with only text. How can I do this? Else if?

Answer (score 0):

Under... 
         `< reference name="product_list" >...`

You will see a `<block>` tag, it will specify what block this is, go to the block class and put the if statement there.

Comment: <?php
    $_productCollection=$this->getLoadedProductCollection();
    $_helper = $this->helper('catalog/output');
?>
<?php if(!$_productCollection->count()): ?>
<p class="note-msg"><?php echo $this->__('There are no products matching the selection.') ?></p>
<?php else: ?>

I added this code but it gives error.

Comment: yeah maybe though maybe the conditional would be better if count was checked == 0

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried this way?

```
<?php
    $_productCollection=$this->getLoadedProductCollection();
    $_helper = $this->helper('catalog/output');
?>
<?php 
  echo $this->getLayout()->createBlock('core/template')->setTemplate('goodtest/test.phtml')->toHtml();
?>
<?php if(!$_productCollection->count()): ?>
<p class="note-msg"><?php echo $this->__('There are no products matching the selection.') ?></p>
<?php else: ?>..........
```